# Analise performance aplicação Java

Tags: java, jsf, desempenho, jboss, stack-trace

Gostaria de saber se existe aplicações para monitoramento de transações para uma aplicação feita em JSF (Servidor JBOSS) com banco de dados SQL Server.

Aplicação está bastante lenta e isso pode esta acorrendo devido as implementações feita em código como consulta para o banco de dados. Essa aplicação está homologada apenas para trabalhar com o navegador da Microsoft, contudo utilizando o Chrome, essa mesma aplicação tem um carregamento melhor nas navegações de pagina, mas algumas funcionalidade não se comporta conforme esperado pelo cliente utilizando o navegado da Google.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma aplicação que monitore toda a execução do fonte e consulta a base de dados. Que eu consiga visualizar os tempo de execução e tentar melhorar o código e script de consulta se possível.

Navegando na internet, encontrei algumas ferramentas como o Prefix e o dynatrace, contudo faz dois dias que eu não consigo configurar meu servidor local (JBoss) para que aplicação consiga monitorar minha aplicação web.